# mv: "Directory not Empty" - how do you merge directories with `mv`?

Tags: mv

I tried to deploy my personal blog website to my remote server recently. When I tried to move a few files and directories to another place by executing `mv`, some unexpected errors happened. The command line echoed "Directory not Empty". After doing some googling, I tried again with '**-f**' switch or '**-v**', the same result showed.
I logged in on the **root** account, and the process is here:

```
root@danielpan:~# shopt -s dotglob
root@danielpan:~# mv /var/www/html/wordpress/* /var/www/html
mv: cannot move `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content` to `/var/www/html/wp-content`: 
Directory not empty
root@danielpan:~# mv -f /var/www/html/wordpress/* /var/www/html
mv: cannot move `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content` to `/var/www/html/wp-content`:
Directory not empty
```

Anybody know why?

(I'm running Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: There are good answers on unix.stackexchange [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127712/merging-folders-with-mv).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution finally. Because the `/var/www/html/wp-content` already exists, then when you try to copy `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content` there, error of `Directory not Empty` happens. So you need to copy `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/*` to `/var/www/html/wp-content`.
Just execute this:

```
mv /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/* /var/www/html/wp-content
rmdir /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content
rmdir /var/www/html/wordpress
```

Comment: which fails if the target directory's wp-content already contains some non-empty directory to which you intended to add files.

Comment: @SilentKnight It's been a while you have answered your question yourself, but just in case you are not aware, maybe it is a bit more comfortable to use `rsync` with the option of `--remove-source-files` in the future?

Answer (score 38):

If You have sub-directories and "mv" is not working:

```
cp -R source/* destination/ 
rm -R source/
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of copying directories by `cp` or `rsync`, I prefer

```sh
cd ${source_path}
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p ${destination_path}/{} \;
find . -type f -exec mv {} ${destination_path}/{} \;
cd $oldpwd
```

moves files (actually renames them) and overwrites existing ones. So it's fast enough.
But when `${source_path}` contains empty subfolders you can cleanup by `rm -rf ${source_path}`

Answer (score 0):

I use `rsync` normally for copying. In case you are running out of space on your hard disk and your destination file structure is more complex (so you can't or don't want to simply delete the destination folder to free the space for moving), you can use the option  `--remove-source-files` ([for more info about this option on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/405761/rsync-remove-source-files-deletes-source-files-one-by-one-or-after-rsync-compl)) of `rsync`! It will asynchronously delete the source files directly after the rsyncing to destination. So you just don't need the double space of disk space, instead it is only a relatively small amount of disk space during the rsyncing. After the rsyncing all disk space is freed from the transferred files. So you could more easily achieve your goal by:

```
$ rsync -avh --remove-source-files --info=progress2 --size-only /var/www/html/wordpress/* /var/www/html
```

In this case I added a progress bar, rsynced with all file attributes and verbosed them and only rsynced files which [differ in size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778889/rsync-difference-between-size-only-and-ignore-times) (which does not matter here as rsync "touches" every file and therefore afterwards it is deleted)